# Drupal 7: Variables in external file access

Tags: 7

Im having a tough time accessing variables from my own external file.

I gave this file:

```
?php include_once('/exercise_names.php'); ?
```

Which contains the following:

```
 ?php 

//Exercise Names

$memory01 = '1'; 
$memory02 = '2';
$memory03 = '3';
$memory04 = '4';

?
```

I cannot get the page to render the names.  I keep getting the following errors:

Notice: Undefined variable: memory01 in eval() (line 4 of /home/webapps/drupal/releases/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Basically its telling me it cant find the required variables, but they are in the file.  For some reason it cannot read the included file.

Any ideas?

thanks, Mac

Comment: Your include statement needs to be in a module file so that it's included in every page load, including the one thats running the eval code. You could put in your themes template.php file I guess, but a custom module is the correct place as @MPD has already mentioned

Answer (score 3):

If I have a module called `foo`, I put all of my includes in a subdirectory called 'inc/' and then use this

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/inc/constants.inc");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/inc/class.FOO.inc");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/inc/class.BAR.inc");
```

in `foo.module`.  If doing Drupal 7, you may also want to take a look at the [files directive for .info files](http://drupal.org/node/542202):

> Drupal now supports a dynamic-loading code registry. To support it,
>   all modules must now declare any code files containing class or
>   interface declarations in the .info file, like so:
>
> ```
> files[] = example.test
> ```
>
> When a module is enabled, Drupal will rescan all declared files and
>   index all the classes and interfaces that it finds. Classes will be
>   loaded automatically by PHP when they are first accessed.

EDIT TO ADDRESS COMMENT

Even if you aren't doing this in a module, you should really abstract out the constants into a module that provides getter functions and/or a static class and/or a singleton with getter functions.

Another option is to bail on includes, and use [`variable_set`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) / [`variable_get`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7), preferably in conjunction with a [module settings form](http://drupal.org/node/206761).

Comment: This isn't a module, just a file of config variable names that I wan to call periodically.  Basically I have a name for an device that I want to use all over the site.  I want to put the names in a file and access them whenever.  If i change the device name it will change it in every location.